# Is "fn ()" treated differently to "fn()" when invoking a function?

Tags: javascript

There are [some conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) when it comes to [using brackets in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8445216/1615483), but do they actually get treated differently when the brackets are used to invoke.

Is `fn ()` different to `fn()` **in any way**, except to the human reader?

Further, is there a difference between `(fn)()` and `fn()`, and if yes which of these to would `fn ()` resemble?

---

For this question `fn` can be any function `function fn() {}` or `var fn = function () {}`

---

**EDIT** : This question isn't "Will they have the same result?", it is about if/how JavaScript compilers treat them.

Comment: Have you actually tried these in an interpreter?

Comment: @millimoose They will all work, that isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: Well, do they work any differently? (Another hint is the word "convention".)

Comment: @millimoose `fn()` and `(1,fn)()` [**are different**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9107367/1615483) but work the same.

Comment: Which is the opposite situation of the one you're asking about. Why should it imply anything significant? There's pretty much an infinite amount of expressions that produce any given value. But in your question, the syntactic differences between your examples are ones that **for any other expression** would have no semantical implications, and in fact certainly don't seem to make a difference when evaluated. What you're asking is tantamount to asking about the difference between `1+1`, `1 + 1`, and `(1) + (1)`

Comment: @alex23 thanks and you seem to be knowledgeable about the spec, but this question isn't about defining `fn`. I'm surprised I haven't seen any answers about opening parenthesis on the next line or the fact `;` are optional yet, I think people got too caught up by my saying the function could have been an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference, `fn () = fn() = (fn)()` but `function fn() {} != var fn = function() {}` because of how [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) works.

Comment: @alex23: There _is_ a substantial difference though. When you do `function foo(){}`, the fact is that `foo` will be available even before declaring the function because of how hoisting (not scoping) works. If you use `var foo = function(){}`, the variable `foo` will be `undefined` until the assignment is parsed, and only at that point you can use the function. The assumption that a function declaration implies that it's attached to the global scope is false; it's attached to the very top of the closest scope (function).

Comment: @alex23: I may agree with you on some points but I think you're wrong about this. I understand that in JS every object (or instance of an object) has a prototype that may or may not be extended but it doesn't change the behavior of how variables are scoped AFAIK...

Comment: It is bad practice to use arguments.callee, if youre on a modern browser use a named function expression and it can refer to itself by name. It is even disallowed in strict iirc

Answer (score 2):

No, `fn()`, `fn ()`, `(fn)()`, and `(fn) ()` all mean the same thing.

Comment: Can you show me an example where they are different?